# Dim screen not working on Ubuntu 20.04 , Assus A17 laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, 20.04, screen

I have a laptop Assus TUF A17 FA706IU-H7101, nvidia card
Ubuntu 20.04 installed.
In additional drivers nvidia-driver-440 selected.

All looks good aside i cannot change the screen dim levels.
If i use dim keys or the settings menu there is no change.

Also the nvidia settings app opens but has no widgets in it:
nvidia-settings 
ERROR: An internal driver error occurred
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

Output of xrandr:
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*

I already looked everywhere for a solution, no luck so far.
This is really annoying as i cant work/look for more then an hour in the laptop because of the brightness.

Anyone has a workaround for this ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this work for you ? "sudo su ; echo 1000 > /sys/class/backlight/your_backlight_device_name/brightness "

Comment: For me it's between the range 0 and 4882.

Comment: I think the problem is that the kernel cannot use mode-setting of your driver. Can you adjust the gamma or resolution or orientation of your screen ?

Comment: And if not , consider switching temporarily to another GPU or install another driver.

Comment: That command didnt do anything , max_brigthness is 49 on a file in that folder. How can i switch to another GPU ?

Comment: Can you adjust it to for example to 30 ? You can switch to your intel accelerated graphics ( if you use intel CPU ) from the nvidia-settings window.

Comment: It changes the file but not the dim levels. You know a way to switch to the onboard GPU ? should be an ATI onboard

Comment: Does changing the settings in the Nvidia-settings work for you ?

Comment: Its in the problem description , the nvidia settings does not work it shows a blank window with no widgets, you can see the error from the shell there.

Comment: So it cannot find your nvidia GPU. Please consider installing a driver version which is compatible with your GPU.

Comment: glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*"
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.1, 128 bits)
This is strange , nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch

Comment: Did you install the driver from repo or from the Nvidia's official .run package ?

Comment: But i installed using addition-drivers utility , and it gave no error in setting about screen it says nvidia driver in use.I will try a restart.

Comment: If everything is installed from the repo , so the problem might be from the nvidia package that ubuntu is providing. It shouldn't give you the Driver/Library mismatch. I've installed nvidia drivers multiple times but never given such a error.

Comment: My Kubuntu 20.04 had Nvidia driver 440 pre-installed and worked nicely.